# SignalR: client disconnection

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr, disconnect

How does the SignalR handle client disconnection? Am I right if I state the following?

- SignalR will detect browser page close/refresh via Javascript event handling and will send appropriate packet to server (through the persisting connection);
- SignalR will NOT detect browser close/network failure (probably only by timeout).

I aim the long-polling transport.

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329932/detect-client-disconnect-with-httplistener) but would like to make it a bit clear for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>If a user refreshes the page, that is treated as a new connection.  You are correct that the disconnect is based on a timeout.</strike>

You can handle the Connect/Reconnect and Disconnect events in a Hub by implementing `SignalR.Hubs.IConnected` and `SignalR.Hubs.IDisconnect`.

The above referred to SignalR 0.5.x.

From [the official documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#connectionlifetime) (currently for v1.1.3):

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        // Add your own code here.
        // For example: in a chat application, record the association between
        // the current connection ID and user name, and mark the user as online.
        // After the code in this method completes, the client is informed that
        // the connection is established; for example, in a JavaScript client,
        // the start().done callback is executed.
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        // Add your own code here.
        // For example: in a chat application, mark the user as offline, 
        // delete the association between the current connection id and user name.
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        // Add your own code here.
        // For example: in a chat application, you might have marked the
        // user as offline after a period of inactivity; in that case 
        // mark the user as online again.
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In SignalR 1.0, the SignalR.Hubs.IConnected and SignalR.Hubs.IDisconnect are no longer implemented, and now it's just an override on the hub itself:

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
}
```